Proving $m = n$ by showing $m\le n$ and $n\le m$
I am reading the book Book of proof to learn proof writing. And I'm currently reading the direct proof section.
It shows an example:

Our next example illustrates a standard technique for showing two
quantities are equal. If we can show $m\le{n}$ and $n\le{m}$ then it follows that
$m=n$. In general, the reasoning involved in showing $m\le{n}$ can be quite
different from that of showing $n\le{m}$.

The proof is based on the proposition: If a,b,c $\in$ N, then $\text{lcm}(ca,cb) = c \text{ lcm}(a,b)$
The proof goes as follows:

First, let $m = \text{lcm}(ca,cb), n = c \text{ lcm}(a,b)$
He prove $m\le{n}$. For $m = \text{lcm}(ca,cb)$, then $\text{lcm} (a,b) = ax = by$ for some $x,y\in{N}$. Besides, $n = c\text{ lcm}(a,b) = cax = cby$. So $n$ is a positive multiple of both $ca$ and $cb$. But $m$ is the smallest positive multiple of both $ca$ and $cb$. Thus $m\le{n}$. But lcm means the least common multiple. Isn't $m=n=cax=cby$ for the same $x,y$ ? Why is $m\le{n}$ ?
He prove $n\le{m}$. For $m$ is a multiple of $ca$ and $cb$, so we have $m = cax = cby$ for some $x,y\in{Z}$. Then $\frac{1}{c}m=ax=by$ is a multiple of both $a$ and $b$. But lcm$(a,b)$ is the least common multiple of both $a$ and $b$. So lcm $(a,b) \le{\frac{1}{c}m}$. So $n\le{m}$. My question here is the same as the second step in the proof.
He draws the conclusion $m=n$.

He said that it's a standard technique to prove equality. I searched the google, but found nowhere using this theorem to prove equality, so I'm asking question here. I am confused about the proof, and I wonder why using lcm to prove equality. Is it a reasonable proof? Are there any other ways to prove number equality?
I am unable to print out lcm in latex, So I didn't enclose the equation in \$\$, sorry for that. For I'm a mse beginner, if you have any suggestions about the way I raise a question, or if you have any questions about this post, please friendly leave them in the comments. Thanks!

I don't understand your question.  The problem involved the lcm, so of course any resolution of it has got to involve the lcm.  The "standard technique" alluded to here is "to show $n=m$ first show $n≤m$ and then show $m≤n$".  Or, possibly "to show $n=m$ first show that $n,|,m$ and then show that $m,|,n$".  Both of those are indeed quite standard.

Side note on formatting: for whatever reason, MathJax doesn't have lcm as a standard function though it does have gcd.  Thus writing \lcm doesn't work where \gcd does.  To get around that, you can use the "text" command.  Thus, \text {lcm} works.

@lulu Thank you for your advice! I understand the proof now, and I'll try to use $\text{lcm}$ next time.


Our next example illustrates a standard technique for showing two
quantities are equal. If we can show $m\leq n$ and $n\leq m$ then it follows that
$m=n$. In general, the reasoning involved in showing $m\leq n$ can be quite
different from that of showing $n\leq m$.

This is indeed a standard technique. One might have expected that the book would show a proof that this technique is valid, that is, it might prove this proposition:
Proposition. If $m\leq n$ and $n\leq m$ then $m=n$.
But there is no proof of this proposition in this book (at least, not near the point where the method based on it is introduced or used). We are left either to prove the proposition ourselves or simply to trust the author.
Perhaps this is the source of your confusion.
Instead of the expected explanation of why we should trust this technique, we get the proof of a proposition that does not prove the validity of this technique; it merely uses this technique.

The proof is based on the proposition: If $a,b,c \in \mathbb N$, then $\operatorname{lcm}(ca,cb) = c \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$.

If you're learning to write proofs, one thing you need to understand is that in the language of proof-writing, your statement above is read like this:

The proof of the fact that if $m\leq n$ and $n\leq m$ then $m=n$ (the most recently mentioned mathematical fact) uses the previously-established fact that if $a,b,c \in \mathbb N$, then $\operatorname{lcm}(ca,cb) = c \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$.

This is completely backwards. The author is not about to use the fact that
$\operatorname{lcm}(ca,cb) = c \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$  if $a,b,c \in \mathbb N$
to prove that $m = n$ if $m\leq n$ and $n\leq m$.
The author is about to use the fact that $m = n$ if $m\leq n$ and $n\leq m$
to prove that $\operatorname{lcm}(ca,cb) = c \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$  if $a,b,c \in \mathbb N$.
So your statement here is the result of a misunderstanding of how to read mathematics (either what the author wrote, or what you wrote; it is unclear which you misunderstood). This makes the question difficult to understand and answer.
Moving along to the author's actual proof of the proposition that
$\operatorname{lcm}(ca,cb) = c \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$  if $a,b,c \in \mathbb N$:

So $n$ is a positive multiple of both $ca$ and $cb$. But $m$ is the smallest positive multiple of both $ca$ and $cb$. Thus $m\leq n$. But lcm means the least common multiple.

The symbol lcm is indeed an abbreviation for "least common multiple." But it is always understood to be a positive number. For example, $12$ is considered the least common multiple of $4$ and $6$ even though $0$ and $-12$ also are multiples of both $4$ and $6$. So reading lcm as "smallest positive multiple of both numbers" is also a correct interpretation. This is what the author has used.

Isn't $m=n=cax=cby$ for the same $x,y$ ?

Yes, it is. But we haven't proved that yet. We're in the process of proving it.
We're going to prove it by proving that
$\operatorname{lcm}(ca,cb) = c \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$.

Why is $m\leq n$ ?

At this point in the proof we know that $m\leq n$ because $m$ and $n$ are both positive and are both multiples of $ca$ and $cb$, but $m$ is the smallest such multiple.
Therefore, while it is possible (indeed it will turn out to be true) that $n = m$,
we know at this point that $m$ is less than or equal to every positive multiple of $ca$ and $cb$, including the multiple $n$.
Above all, if $m = n$ (as will turn out to be true), it is certainly also true that $m \leq n$, is it not? Would you argue that the statement $12 \leq 12$ is false?

For $m$ is a multiple of $ca$ and $cb$, so we have $m = cax = cby$ for some $x,y\in \mathbb Z$.

This may or may not have been clear to you, but the $x$ and $y$ in this part of the proof are not assumed to be the same $x$ and $y$ as in the previous part of the proof.
(It turns out that they are the same $x$ and $y$, but the author doesn't use that fact because he hasn't proved it yet.)
Your main question on that part of the proof has the same answer as the previous part. We use the conditions of the proposition ($a,b,c \in \mathbb N$),
definitions such as the definition of lcm, previously proved propositions,
and other facts developed earlier in the proof in order to establish the truth of new statements. We do not use things that we know but that have not yet appeared in the development of the proposition.

It is an odd example to choose, because the proof feels like it's falling short of some intuitive leaps. I haven't encountered the lcm approach for proving equality; I think the author used it just as an example of how to go about proving if you had to use lcm, not implying you would normally use lcm.
As for why the proof works, it may be hard to explain the perspective. Looking at the $m\leq n$ case, we know that $n$ is some  multiple of $ca$ and $cb$, but so far we haven't proved that it is the least multiple. Perhaps there exists some other $x', y' \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $cax'=cay' < cax = cay$. We haven't proved that this is impossible, so we can't say yet that $n = m$. But because $m$ is the least multiple (by definition of step 1), we can at least say $m \leq n$.

Thank you for answering my question and helping me with the latex in the problem description! Your explanation is so clear! I love it!
